# "user-select: none" and strange behaviour in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, formatting, stylesheet

I am trying to prevent text highlighting in Firefox for some, but not all elements on the page.  Consider the following:

```
<div style="-moz-user-select: none;">
I cannot be highlighted
    <div  style="-moz-user-select: text;">
    I should be highlightable, but am not.
    </div>
</div>
```

As I understand it, using the above css rules, the text of the inner div should be highlightable.  However this does not appear to work.  In practice none of the text can be highlighted.

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong?  If not, does anyone know of a workaround for this situation?

Thanks!

ps I should add that using the alternate...

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

...in the above example works just fine in webkit browsers

Comment: I have a web app that does a lot of dragging and dropping.  Accidental mouseclicks can cause highlighting, which is harmless - but can be confusing to the user.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace

```
<div style="-moz-user-select: none;">
```

with

```
<div style="-moz-user-select: -moz-none;">
```

The [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-select) of the `-moz-user-select` property states that `-moz-none` means that the text of the element and sub-elements cannot be selected, but selection can be enabled on sub-elements using `-moz-user-select: text;`

Comment: What caught me was using -moz-user-select: all. For some reason, that doesn't work and you need to use -moz-user-select: text.

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla informs the following about the `none` property :

> The text of the element and *sub-elements* will appear as if they
>   cannot be selected. Any use of
>   Selection however will contain these
>   elements.

Read [-moz-user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-select).

Comment: That is true.  However the inner -moz-user-select is still not being properly applied.  In practice everything may be highlighted - but only the inner text should *appear* to be highlighted.

Comment: No matter what this property does, the inner div is a *sub-element* of the outer div.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try `onmousedown="return false"` and you can change the cursor if you don't want the selection or pointer with `cursor:`