# HTML - Can't move cursor inside textarea when CSS is on

Tags: css, forms, html, textarea

I have a super simple HTML form:

```
<form name="editor" action="#" method="POST">
    <textarea name="contents" cols="100" rows="50"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Text echoed inside it is HTML code.

Now, when CSS is turned off, it works perfectly.

But when it's turned on, I:

- can't click anywhere inside the textarea text to place the cursor there
- can't move cursor with arrow keys, it will only move a few characters left and right, and if up/down arrows are pressed, it moves the cursor to the very top/very bottom of the textarea.

What have I tried:

- Excluding the textarea from CSS firebug showed applied to it
- Trying with or without JS to check if that makes a difference
- Tried different browsers, same issue repeats
- Turning off CSS completely and then it works, but it's not an option

The only idea I have is that maybe the textarea is inheriting some CSS from somewhere, but what kind of CSS would cause such behavior, what to look for?

Here's the CSS as seen by firebug:

```
textarea {
    overflow: auto;
    resize: vertical;
    vertical-align: top;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
html, button, input, select, textarea {
    color: #222222;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Thanks for any replies!

Comment: "Text echoed inside it is HTML code": *escaped* html code, I presume? If not, that may be throwing your code off. Either way, there must be something else in play here: the code you posted doesn't show the symptoms, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssb4K/).

Comment: did u tried it the other browsers such as chrome,ff,safari, opera ?

Comment: @aspirinemaga yes he did, he said it appears in other browsers too.

Comment: it works in my browsers... all of em.. :) :O

Comment: do `var_dump($text)` and show what's inside.

Comment: please give us a fiddle so we can check the full code. nothing's wrong with the css you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks everyone!  You actually helped me by setting this fiddle, I started pasting part by part of CSS there, and here's what caused the issue, if anyone gets into same problem:

```
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Basically disabled text selection was obviously inherited from body.

Thanks everyone again.

PS. Also to clarify to anyone who suspected that my code inside textarea was unescaped - yes it was, but that doesn't seem to be a problem, you obviously can do that.

Comment: As an addendum to this, if you want to disable selection on an outer element, and re-enable it for a textarea inside that element, then see  [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077950/user-select-none-and-strange-behaviour-in-firefox).